# File input loses upload handler function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout

I have a simple form with file input and a state with an error flag. If the user tries to submit the form without a file, the error flag is set to true. After that, useEffect in the error component triggers a timeout that will set the error flag to false after 3 seconds. If the user opens the download window before the error flag becomes false, the download function no longer works.

My Home component:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState<File | null>(null)
  const [error, setError] = useState<boolean>(false)

  const onUploadFile = useCallback((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setFile(event.target.files?.[0] || null)
  }, [])

  const onSubmit = (event: FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (!file) {
      setError(true)
      return
    }
    console.log(file.name)
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="form">
        <input type={'file'} accept={'.txt,.zip,.csv,.xlsx'} onChange={onUploadFile}/>
        {file && <p>{file.name}</p>}
        <button type={'submit'}>Submit</button>
      </form>
      {error && <Error message={'Error'} close={setError}/>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

My error component:

```
interface ErrorProps {
    message: string
    close: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>
}

const Error:FC<ErrorProps> = ({message, close}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setTimeout(() => close(false), 3000)

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timerId)
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="error">
      <p>{message}</p>
      <p style={{cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={() => close(false)}>&times;</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I guess that while the upload window is open and timeout calls setState function, Home component is re-rendered and upload function recreated, but input tag save a pointer on a previos function. I tried to pass upload function in useCallback in the hope that the reference to the function will be permanent, but it`s not working. What can I do?

Comment: Where is your download function? The close() that is passed in to your Error effectively calls setFile(undefined), but it's not clear how that affects the downloading. Could you do something that cancels the timeout (like removing the Error from the DOM) when the download window opens?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I added a false flag to the close function. I tried setting the error flag to false before opening the download window, but that doesn't work. Most likely, the render is called after the window is opened and the function is recreated anyway.